# How to gets the number of overlapping days between 2 ranges?

Tags: c#, date, range

let me explain the situation first - let's say i have 4 dates: BS, BE, PS, PE (S for start, E for end).
I need to know how many days are over lapping when given those dates.
for example : BE-05.01 , BS-10.01, PS-03.01, PE-07.01
the result is: 3 (05.01, 06.01 and 07.01 are overlapping)

I wrote the following code but it seems to messy and i want to check if maybe there is a simpler way to do this:

```
private static double GetNumOfOverLappingDays(DateTime BS, DateTime BE, DateTime PS, DateTime PE)
    {
        //case 1:
        //                  |--- B ---|
        //                  |----P ---|

        //case 2:
        //                  |--- B ---|
        //                          | --- P --- |

        //case 3:
        //                  |--- B ---|
        //          | --- P ---- |

        //case 4:
        //                  |--- B ---|
        //                     | - P - |

        //case 5:
        //                  |--- B ---|
        //              | -------- P -------- |

        double days = -1;
        bool isNotOverLap = (BS > PE) || (PS > BE);

        if (isNotOverLap == false)
        {
            //case 1
            if (BS == PS && BS == PE)
            {
                days = (PE - PS).TotalDays;
            }
            //case 2
            else if (BE > PS && BE < PE)
            {
                days = (BE - PS).TotalDays;
            }
            //case 3
            else if (BS > PS && BS < PE)
            {
                days = (PE - BS).TotalDays;
            }
            //case 4
            else if (BS < PS && BE > PE)
            {
                days = (PE - PS).TotalDays;
            }
            //case 5
            else if (BS > PS && BE < PE)
            {
                days = (BE - PS).TotalDays;
            }
        }
        return days+1;
    }
```

thanks in advance for any assitance,

Amit

Comment: If these are meant to be *dates*, then you need to work out whether you want to be inclusive or exclusive of the end date, for one thing. For example, suppose they're *all* January 1st 2014. Treating the values as dates, I'd expect an overlap of 1 day in that case - but your code will give 0 days. Date ranges typically include the end point, whereas date/time ranges don't. This is just one reason for [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) having `LocalDate` as a separate type...

Comment: you are coorect. i'm adding +1 to the "days" value to fix this

Comment: Please indicate that in the question then - it'll make it clearer.

Comment: To echo Jon's comment - ranges that include time typically are expressed as half-open intervals, `[start, end)`, where the end time is excluded.  For example, if I say an event takes place from `1:00 - 2:00`, I usually mean that 2:00 is *not* in the range because the event is over then.  But for date-only ranges (where the time portion of a `DateTime` is ignored), those are typically *fully-inclusive* ranges, `[start, end]`, such as when I say `Jan 1 - Jan 31`.  Decide which you'll be working with, as it *does* affect the logic in your implementation.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
    private static double GetOverlappingDays(DateTime firstStart, DateTime firstEnd, DateTime secondStart, DateTime secondEnd)
    {
        DateTime maxStart = firstStart > secondStart ? firstStart : secondStart;
        DateTime minEnd = firstEnd < secondEnd ? firstEnd : secondEnd;
        TimeSpan interval = minEnd - maxStart;
        double returnValue = interval > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0) ? interval.TotalDays : 0;
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: This would be *much* clearer if you used appropriate whitespace, and made your variables follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've probably become too dependent on the VS IDE to place whitespace for me. As for naming conventions, could you give an example? I've been trying to break the habit of using Hungarian Notation, normally I would have named MaxStart dtMaxStart, and so on.

Comment: I'm suggesting `maxStart` and `minEnd` etc, rather than `MaxStart` etc. Use `camelCase` for variables, not `PascalCase`.

Comment: Interesting, when rendering code blocks StackOverflow seems to differentiate between variables and Types based on case...

Comment: You might want to edit: TimeSpan interval = minEnd.AddDays(1) - maxStart; in case of the second date range is one day (both secondStart and secondEnd are the same date).

Comment: In the OP's example, a range of one whole day seems to be represented by BS:01.01 BE:02.01, as fas as I can infer from the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use for loop:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2013,12,1),
            d2 = new DateTime(2013,12,14),
            d3 = new DateTime(2013,12,10),
            d4 = new DateTime(2013,12,20);
int count = 0;

for (var d = d1.Date; d <= d2.Date; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
      if (d >= d3.Date && d <= d4.Date)
           count++;
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Notice that this code gives integer value. If you need value in hours this code will not fit. Also this is not the most efficient approach, but it's simple and works ok for small ranges.

Comment: If you use this approach, computing the value for two ranges that span 10 years will take 3650 times more time than computing the value for ranges that span one day.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two strongly related values, like start and end date, then it's good idea to have [object which will hold them both](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html). Consider creating `DateRange` class:

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        if (start > end) throw new ArgumentException();

        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }
    public double TotalDays { get { return (End - Start).TotalDays; } }

    public bool Includes(DateTime value)
    {
        return (Start <= value) && (value <= End);
    }

    public DateRange Intersect(DateRange range)
    {
        if (range.Includes(Start))
            return new DateRange(Start, (End < range.End) ? End : range.End);

        if (range.Includes(End))
            return new DateRange(range.Start, End);

        if (Start < range.Start && range.End < End)
            return range;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static double GetNumOfOverLappingDays(DateRange b, DateRange p)
{
   DateRange overlap = b.Intersect(p);
   if (overlap == null)
       return 0;

   return overlap.TotalDays;
}
```

Create date ranges and pass them to this method:

```
var b = new DateRange(new DateTime(2013, 12, 20), new DateTime(2013, 12, 25));
var p = new DateRange(new DateTime(2013, 12, 22), new DateTime(2013, 12, 26)); 
double totalDays = GetNumOfOverLappingDays(b, p);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this to **get overlapping range between two time ranges**, you can get the number of overlapping days easily from the result

```cs
public static (DateTime, DateTime)? GetOverlappingTimeRange((DateTime, DateTime) firstTimeRange, 
                                                            (DateTime, DateTime) secondTimeRange)
{
    var leftIndex = Math.Max(firstTimeRange.Item1.Ticks, secondTimeRange.Item1.Ticks);
    var rightIndex = Math.Min(firstTimeRange.Item2.Ticks, secondTimeRange.Item2.Ticks);

    if (leftIndex > rightIndex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return (new DateTime(leftIndex), new DateTime(rightIndex));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to calculate the latest start and earliest end and then subtract the two. Note that this example can return negative numbers if the time is not overlapping at all, but this was not one of the 5 cases you mentioned.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime start1 = new DateTime(2013,1,2);
        DateTime end1 = new DateTime(2013,1,14);

        DateTime start2 = new DateTime(2013,1,1);
        DateTime end2 = new DateTime(2013,1,12);

        DateTime lateStart = GetLatest(start1, start2);
        DateTime earlyEnd = GetEarliest(end1, end2);

        Console.WriteLine((earlyEnd-lateStart).TotalDays + 1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static DateTime GetEarliest(DateTime start1, DateTime start2)
    {
        return start1 < start2 ? start1 : start2;
    }

    private static DateTime GetLatest(DateTime start1, DateTime start2)
    {
        return start1 > start2 ? start1 : start2;
    }
```